# Can [untagged] have a tag wiki?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki

I try to keep an eye on [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and keep its population low.  A couple of days ago it occurred to me that a tag wiki inviting others to do the same might be a good idea and so submitted an edit for consideration.

Shortly afterward, I was [awarded the reputation for an accepted edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1980/ben-blank?tab=reputation).  However, the edit doesn't seem to have "taken":

1. The [tag page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) has no wiki/description block at the top.
2. The link in my reputation tab is to a [nonexistant question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/34382) (for my previous wiki edits, the link redirects to [the appropriate tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/22501)).  Similarly, you get a 404 if you attempt to visit the [tag's info page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged/info) directly.

Is there something about the [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag which prevents it from having a wiki?  *Should* it have a wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a tag gets cleared of all questions, it is deleted from the database. This deletes its association from the tag wikis it had, which become [orphan.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2039) There was already [another tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/16730/revisions) for untagged that got orphaned before that one too.

Moderators have access to the [list of orphan wikis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/admin/orphan-wikis) so that content isn't lost, but that's beside the point.

The point is, *no*, [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) doesn't get to have a tag wiki because it shouldn't exist in the first place. Please reject all suggested edits for this tag wiki.

Comment: Then shouldn't that be changed?  Clearly, I'm not the only who's felt it could do with a little explanation.  ;-)

Comment: @Ben http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111508/users-can-suggest-tag-wikis-for-untagged